# Haskell Syntax - How to write let in bracketed do block?

Tags: haskell, syntax

The following code got "parse error" on the let clause (in GHC 7.8.3):

```
someFunction = do {
    let foo = bar;
    return foo;
}
```

How to correct it in order to get the equivalent to this?

```
someFunction = do
    let foo = bar
    return foo
```

Comment: In Haskell `;` is a separator (as in `{a;b;c}`), not a terminator (as in `{a;b;c;}`). Hence, remove the last `;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
someFunction = do {
    let foo = bar
  ; return foo
}
```

or

```
someFunction = do {
    let { foo = bar };
    return foo
}
```